# what's wrong with this code?

Tags: mysql, database

this is my code which will not work correctly ! what is wrong with its data type :( thanks

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (A INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE T3 (A SMALLINT NOT NULL);
INSERT T1 VALUES (32768.5);
SELECT * FROM T1;
INSERT T3 SELECT * FROM T1;
SELECT * FROM T3;
```

Comment: could you help me that just the errors that will be occured are for lines 3 and 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

32768.5 is not an integer, and it's too big to fit in a smallint.

Comment: Mysql numeric max reference

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: could you help me that just the errors that will be occured are for lines 3 and 4?

Comment: @user328920, how about posting the errors you got?  As I said, if you want to store 32768.5 in a field, don't make it INTEGER.  If you want to make the column INTEGER, then don't try to store a non-integer in it.